# Reverse foreach results

Tags: php

im trying to reverse the results in my foreach loop, I am aware that I could try using array_reverse however that does not reverse the output of the loop.

the results currently look like this

```
[new Date(2012, 05, 16), 630.10, 615.94],
[new Date(2012, 05, 15), 615.00, 603.75],
[new Date(2012, 05, 14), 608.50, 600.58],
[new Date(2012, 05, 11), 614.55, 604.77],
[new Date(2012, 05, 10), 616.19, 610.23],
```

the output I want is

```
[new Date(2012, 05, 10), 616.19, 610.23], 
[new Date(2012, 05, 11), 614.55, 604.77],
[new Date(2012, 05, 14), 608.50, 600.58],
[new Date(2012, 05, 15), 615.00, 603.75],
[new Date(2012, 05, 16), 630.10, 615.94],
```

this is my code.

```
foreach($stockcontentex as $stockexplode){
    $stockex = explode(',',$stockcontentex[$i++]);
    $stockexdate = explode('-', $stockex[0]);
    $stockYear = $stockexdate[0];
    $stockMonth = $stockexdate[1];
    $stockDay = $stockexdate[2];
    $stockHigh = $stockex[2];
    $stockLow = $stockex[3];
    $_str .= '[new Date('.$stockYear.', '.$stockMonth.', '.$stockDay.'), '.$stockHigh.', '.$stockLow.'],'. "\n";

    }
```

any help is appreciated, im not sure if there is any additional info that may be needed.

thanks

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: take a look at the updated code

Comment: What is `$i`? I think you are confusing `foreach` with `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_reverse` and then swap this:

```
$stockex = explode(',',$stockcontentex[$i++]);
```

with this:

```
$stockex = explode(',',$stockexplode);
```

Alternately, you could switch `.=` for:

```
 $_str = '[new Date('.$stockYear.', '.$stockMonth.
           ', '.$stockDay.'), '.$stockHigh.', '.$stockLow.'],'. "\n" . $_str;
```

Comment: theres alot more to the code but the loop was giving me the problem. This isnt all of the code but just an idea of what i am doing http://pastebin.com/iwbbBwt2

Comment: i like your alternative however it keeps displaying the results outside of the loop instead of inside, this is what i did http://pastebin.com/sPa1jWJm

Answer (score 0):

Although I personally would go with @cwallenpoole's answer, an alternative would be:

```
$stockcount = count($stockcontentex);
for ($i = $stockcount; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $stockex = explode(',',$stockcontentex[$i++]);
    $stockexdate = explode('-', $stockex[0]);
    $stockYear = $stockexdate[0];
    $stockMonth = $stockexdate[1];
    $stockDay = $stockexdate[2];
    $stockHigh = $stockex[2];
    $stockLow = $stockex[3];
    $_str .= '[new Date('.$stockYear.', '.$stockMonth.', '.$stockDay.'), '.$stockHigh.', '.$stockLow.'],'. "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this approach for reversing the traversal of the loop over an array:
*(in this case a simulated reverse foreach)*

```
if(!empty($array)) {
    $value = end($array);
    $key = key($array);
    do {

        /**
         * Do your stuff here
         * Could be old code/stuff here that worked with foreach($array as $key => $value)
         */

        $value = prev($array);
        $key = key($array);
    } while($key !== null);
}
```

**Note:** It's a bit of a hack. But it should work for every kind of (associative) array you want to traverse over in reverse.